# Hover won't work on button using position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

I tried using z-index to place an image in the background (since I'm using a background color to create overlay) of headers/buttons on a landing page but I could not get it to work until I positioned the headers/buttons as absolute. Now the buttons (which obviously need to be clicked) cannot be hovered or selected.

The landing page is split in half, I didn't place the background image on the bottom half and the button hovers fine but on the top half I left the background image and I cannot hover over the buttons. If you find a solution please explain how I misunderstood too.

http://codepen.io/levane/pen/NNBOdM?editors=1100

```
<body>
    <section id="landing-page">
      <nav>
        <button id="contact">Contact</button>
      </nav>
      <div id="top-half">
        <header>
          <h1>Artemis Levane</h1>
          <h2>Web Designer & Front-End Developer</h2>
          <button id="about-btn">Who I Am</button>
        </header><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442328166075-47fe7153c128?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;s=e18fcc3c0c7149c8ce315a176be812f0"/>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-half">
    <header>
      <h3>Helping businesses & individuals bring their brands to the web</h3>
      <button id="work-btn">What I Do</button>
    </header><img src="/Personal/Images/Logo.png"/><br/>
    <div id="bounce">
      <button id="finger">☟</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: Antonio;
}

#landing-page {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  font-family: Antonio;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#top-half {
  height: 340px;
  background: rgb(27, 40, 57);
  color: rgb(240, 202, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top-half header {
  width: 50%;
  height: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#top-half img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

#landing-page header h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 500%;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#landing-page header h2 {
  font-size: 23;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#about-btn {
  border: 5px solid rgb(240, 202, 0);
  padding: 5px 40px;
  color: rgb(240, 202, 0);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#about-btn:hover {
  color: rgb(27, 40, 57);
  background: rgb(240, 202, 0);
}

#contact {
  padding: 5px 40px;
  color: rgb(240, 202, 0);
  border: 3.5px solid rgb(240, 202, 0);
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 87%;
  margin-top: 1.1%;
}

#contact:hover {
  color: rgb(27, 40, 57);
  background: rgb(240, 202, 0);
}

#bottom-half {
  height: 340px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 246, 222);
  color: rgb(27, 40, 57);
}

#bottom-half header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 24.8%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

#bottom-half header h3 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#bottom-half img {
  height: 87%;
  margin-left: 470.5px;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  opacity: .1;
}

#work-btn {
  border: 5px solid rgb(27, 40, 57);
  padding: 5px 40px;
  color: rgb(27, 40, 57);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin-left: 29.7%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#work-btn:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 246, 222);
  background: rgb(27, 40, 57);
}

/*   ☟  FINGER BOUNCE  ☟   */

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

#finger {
  margin-top: -10%;
  font-size: 35px;
}

#bounce {
  -moz-animation: bounce 4s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 4s infinite;
  animation: bounce 4s infinite;
}


/*   END FINGER BOUNCE   */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the stacking order by setting a higher [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value.

```
nav {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#top-half header {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZjPjO?editors=1100)**